# Disabling a database for testing when multiple databases configured

Tags: django

I have two databases configured in my app:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': { ... }
    'legacy': { ... }
}
```

The legacy database is only used in a particular part of the app (I've added it as a second database for convenience).

This works fine, except that when I try to run tests, Django tried to create a test database for the legacy database, causing an error:

> Got an error creating the test database: (1044, "Access denied for user ... to to database 'test_...'")

How can I tell Django not to create a test database for the second legacy database?

I thought setting the following would work:

```
DATABASES['legacy']['TEST'] = {
    'NAME': None,
    'CREATE_DB': False
}
```

but that doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems looks like a common issue with multiples databases and testing in Django. Here is the way I generally deal with it.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': { ... }
    'legacy': { ... }
}
# You can add here any other type of control (not prod, debug == True, etc.)
if "test" in sys.argv:
    del DATABASES["legacy"]
    # Or
    DATABASES = { "default": DATABASES["default"] }
```

This works great in the case you have only one setting file, you can easily adapt for other cases.

If you are handling many databases another option could be to start from the ground up inside your tests settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': { ... }
    'legacy': { ... }
}
# You can add here any other type of control (not prod, debug == True, etc.)
if "test" in sys.argv:
    DATABASES = {"default": {}}
    DATABASES["default"]["ENGINE"] = "django.db.backends.sqlite3"
    # Etc... Add want you need here.
```